# Hiding infoWindow of ArcGIS API for JavaScript while using measure tool?

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.1, popup

In my Javascript API Web application I'm using the infoWindow to query a parcel layer and display display information in a popup when I click the parcel. I've set this functionality to turn on and off depending on if the parcel is visible, and I control the visibility of my different layers with check boxes in a legend.

Every time the parcel layer is checked on of off it calls the clickConnect function with a value of true or false. Depending on this, click connect will call the executeIdentifyTask function, which query's the parcel layer, when clicked, and displays the info in a popup. This works great unless I try to use the esri.dijit.Measurement tool while the parcel layer is turned on. In which case i still get a pop up every time I click, which gets in the way of me measuring parcels.

Is there a way that I could turn the popup/query functionality off while I'm using the measure tool and the parcel layer is turned on? I'm a bit of a beginner at using javascript/dojo so I'm not sure how to do this. I've searched the ESRI forums for answers to this question without much success thus far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I hope I was clear in my explanation, if not let me know!

Javascript from my map app relevant to the question:

```
  var app = {};
  app.map = null; 

  var legendLayers = [];
  var clickHandler;

  function init() {
    //add popup
     var popup = new esri.dijit.Popup({
      fillSymbol: new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 2), new dojo.Color([255,255,0,0.25]))
    }, dojo.create("div"));
    //add geometry service
    esri.config.defaults.geometryService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://server/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer");
    //initalize map
    app.map = new esri.Map("map", {
      basemap : "streets",
      center : [-111.924531, 40.611871],
      zoom : 13,
      infoWindow: popup
    });
    //add  parcel layer
     var parcels = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://server/arcgis/rest/services/Parcels_UT/MapServer", {
      id : 'parcels',
      visible : false
    });
    legendLayers.push({
      layer : parcels,
      title : 'Parcels'
    });
    //add parcel query data
    var content = "<b>Address</b>: ${ADDR}" + "<br /><b>Owner Name</b>: ${OWNER}" + "<br /><b>Parcel ID</b>: ${APN}" + "<br /><b>City</b>: ${CITY}" + "<br /><b>Acres</b>: ${TOTAL_ACRE}" + " <br /><a href='${COUNTY_LIN}'>County Assessor Site</a>"   
    var popUpTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("Parcel", content);
    //add paercel layer as feature layer
    var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://server/arcgis/rest/services/Parcels_UT/MapServer/0",{
      mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,
      outFields: ["*"],
      infoTemplate:popUpTemplate
    });

    //create legend
    dojo.connect(app.map, 'onLayersAddResult', function(results) {
      var legend = new esri.dijit.Legend({
        map : app.map,
        layerInfos : legendLayers
      }, "legendDiv");
      legend.startup();
    });
    app.map.addLayers([parcels]);

    dojo.connect(app.map, 'onLayersAddResult', function(results) {

      //add legend check boxes
      dojo.forEach(legendLayers, function(layer) {
        var layerName = layer.title;
        var checkBox = new dijit.form.CheckBox({
          name : "checkBox" + layer.layer.id,
          value : layer.layer.id,
          checked : layer.layer.visible,
          onChange : function(evt) {
            var clayer = app.map.getLayer(this.value);
            clayer.setVisibility(!clayer.visible);
            this.checked = clayer.visible;


            //toggle the feature layer with the parcel layer
            if (this.value ==="parcels" && this.checked === true){
                clickConnect(true);
                console.log("parcels");
            } else if (this.value ==="parcels"){
                clickConnect(false);
                console.log("noParcels");
            }

          }
        });

        //add the check box and label to the table of contnents
        dojo.place(checkBox.domNode, dojo.byId("toggle"), "after");
        var checkLabel = dojo.create('label', {
          'for' : checkBox.name,
          innerHTML : layerName
        }, checkBox.domNode, "after");
        dojo.place("<br />", checkLabel, "after");
      });
    });        

    dojo.connect(app.map, 'onLoad', function(map) {
      initToolbar(app.map);
    });

     function executeIdentifyTask(evt) {
      var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
      query.geometry = pointToExtent(app.map,evt.mapPoint,10);
      var deferred = featureLayer.selectFeatures(query,esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
      app.map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
      app.map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);

    }

     function clickConnect(connect){
  if(connect){
    //perform the identify task on click 
    clickHandler = dojo.connect(app.map, "onClick", executeIdentifyTask);
  }else{
    //disconnect the click handler 
    dojo.disconnect(clickHandler);
    clickHandler = null;
  }

 }       
  }

  function initToolbar(mymap) {
    //define a new line symbol and point symbol to use for measure tools
    var pms = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("images/flag.png", 24, 24);
    pms.setOffset(9, 11);
    var sls = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DOT, new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0, .55]), 4);
    var measurement = new esri.dijit.Measurement({
      map : mymap,
      lineSymbol : sls,
      pointSymbol : pms
    }, dojo.byId('measurementDiv'));
    measurement.startup();
    measurement.setTool("area", false);

  }

  function pointToExtent(map, point, toleranceInPixel) {
   var pixelWidth = map.extent.getWidth() / map.width;
   var toleraceInMapCoords = toleranceInPixel * pixelWidth;
   return new esri.geometry.Extent( point.x - toleraceInMapCoords,
                point.y - toleraceInMapCoords,
                point.x + toleraceInMapCoords,
                point.y + toleraceInMapCoords,
                map.spatialReference );                           
  }

  dojo.ready(init);
```

Comment: did you end up using the answer below? I am trying to hide the popup while measuring but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a listener to the show and hide events of the measurement tool:

```
dojo.connect(measurement, "show", function(){      
   //Then disconnect your onclick event for parcels layers
});
```

Then just connect the event when the measure tool is hidden.

```
dojo.connect(measurement, "hide", function(){
   //Connect your onclick event for parcels layers
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not listed in the [documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jsapi/#measurement), but you can access the functions that control the Measurement Widget through areaToggleButton and distanceToggleButton. Here's an example using your your initToolbar function.

```
function initToolbar(mymap) {
    //define a new line symbol and point symbol to use for measure tools
    var pms = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("images/flag.png", 24, 24);
    pms.setOffset(9, 11);
    var sls = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DOT, new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0, .55]), 4);
    var measurement = new esri.dijit.Measurement({
        map : mymap,
        lineSymbol : sls,
        pointSymbol : pms
    }, dojo.byId('measurementDiv'));
    measurement.startup();
    measurement.setTool("area", false);

    // make measurement buttons turn off clickhandler when clicked
    measurement.areaToggleButton = function () {
        this.clearResult();
        this.setTool("area");
        dojo.disconnect(clickHandler);
    };

    measurement.distanceToggleButton= function () {
        this.clearResult();
        this.setTool("distance");
        dojo.disconnect(clickHandler);
    };
}
```

Comment: That's interesting to know!